# Why static property of non-static class is not available in razor view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, static

I have a non-static class Institute, i cannot use static property DisplayPicturePath if the object is not passed into this view. However if i use Static class with static method then that is available in view. some suggestions if my approach is wrong?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create() {      
    //if do not pass institute into view
    //Institute institute = new Institute();
    return View();          
}
```

My razor view has this

```
<div class="ui segment">
    <img id="DisplayPicture_img" alt="Institute Picture" class="ui fluid image" src="@Url.Content(Path.Combine(Institute.DisplayPicturePath ,"univeristy.jpg"))" />
</div>
```

and my class is this

```
public class Institute
{
    public Institute()
    {
        DisplayPicture = "institute.png";
        Scholarships = new List<Scholarship>();
        ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public static string DisplayPicturePath
    {
        get
        {
            return @"\\"+ Path.Combine("Content", "images", "DisplayPictures");        
        }
    } 

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("Institute Id")]
    public int InstituteId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Institute Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }}
}
```

how ever i am using another static class to use this way

```
<div class="ui segment">
    <img id="DisplayPicture_img" alt="intitute Picture" class="ui fluid image" src="@Url.Content(Path.Combine(UtilityMethods.GetDisplayPicturePath(PictureType.Institute),"univeristy.jpg"))" />
</div>
```

my static class is

```
public static class UtilityMethods
{
    public static string GetDisplayPicturePath(PictureType type) 
    {
        if (type.Equals(PictureType.Institute))
        {
            return @"\\" + Path.Combine("Content", "images", "DisplayPictures", "Institute");
        }
        else if(type.Equals(PictureType.User))
        {
            return @"\\" + Path.Combine("Content", "images", "DisplayPictures", "User");
        }
        else if (type.Equals(PictureType.Scholarship))
        {
            return @"\\" + Path.Combine("Content", "images", "DisplayPictures", "Scholarship");
        }
        else
        {
            return @"\\" + Path.Combine("Content", "images");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you see? Did you add namespace references of class at the top of the page?

Comment: its a null reference error, just like a non-static property would get if you dont  pass in through view

Comment: Did you try accessing `Institute.DisplayPicturePath` in server code and see if its working fine there?

Comment: Yes i tried exactly this, and it didnot work, i was getting null reference error. but when a complete static class was used it was working fine..

Comment: Then its problem in the code of static property. Try returning some constant string and see it works.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hey do you think a static "method" will work? i didnt tried that

Comment: i also tried constant string but didnt tried it fully since i am using Path.Combine and it was giving some error that it cant be constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Build Issue or Chrome browser cache clearance issue, Since Static property was available in my Controller but for some reason not available in view AT THE SAME TIME.

Just after a dinner break and good sleep. i rechecked it by creating tons of test scenarios and come to the point that original method was working after all.

Static properties are definitely available in view.
weather they are in Method form, Const string form or called from Non-Static class.

Answer (score -2):

You can not access the property in view if it is not static unless you pass that in model

`[HttpGet]

```
public ActionResult Create() {

    //if do not pass institute into view
    Institute institute = new Institute();

institute.DisplayPicturePath=//Whatever value you wanna set here;
    return View(institute);

}`
```

> View:@model Institute 
>         src="@Url.Content(Model.DisplayPicturePath)" />

Comment: The OP is clearly using static methods, this do not answer the question at all.